# Github Pages Jekyll posts time off

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have this time in my posts markdown `2016-08-25 17:00:00 -0500`

but Github Pages is displaying my post on the 26th...

Github is also doing this weird thing with my time in the preview of my post markdown files on Githubs website.
[image]

How do I fix the timezone on my Github page? It's screwing up the post urls I want to link to.

Github is forcing my posts to -0700 and I'm trying to use -0500.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In your `_config.yml`, set :

```
timezone: America/New_York
```

or [whatever timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) you're in.